# shopware app doesn't work in test environment without running build-storefront.js from console?

Tags: shopware6, shopware6-app

I have an app for shopware 6 which has a javascript file.
After i upload it to my shopware6 site, install and activate it, it doesn't work unless i run the build-storefront.sh from console.

Is there a way to make the app work without running build-storefront.sh ?

I tested it with shopware 6.4.14.0

Comment: Did you install/activate the app through the web-interface or by CLI?

Comment: i uploaded it from the admin extensions page

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All assets like the javascript of your app need to be uploaded inside your app, so the app automatically works without the need to rebuild the storefront after installing your app.

Therefore to create a zip folder for publishing or for uploading you should always execute the `build-storefront.sh` script, either locally or in a CI step. That command should build all the necessary assets and put them under the `Resources/app/storefront/dist` folder inside your app.

Please ensure that that folder is included in the zip file you upload to your shop.

Comment: thanks! this worked. i haven't found anything documented about this step.

Comment: You already knew, to use build-storefront, what made the difference. This answer does not tell anything new. I have the same problem. What exactly made it work? Thanks.